# Problems with nodejs

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

It's running on Ubuntu 17.04 and I'm trying to execute nodejs cf.js, but I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Problem with log4js configuration: ({ appenders:
   [ { type: 'console' },
     { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site_1500582320.log' } ] }) - must have a property "appenders" of type object.
    at tests.forEach (/var/www/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:38:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Configuration.throwExceptionIf (/var/www/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:36:11)
    at new Configuration (/var/www/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:195:10)
    at Object.configure (/var/www/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/log4js.js:172:12)
    at updateLog (/var/www/bot/cf.js:32:9)
    at Object. (/var/www/bot/cf.js:29:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not ubuntu related, based on this doc - configuration format has changed. For example, the format has changed from:

```
log4js.configure({
appenders: [
{ type: 'console' },
{ type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' }
]
});
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
```

To

```
log4js.configure({
appenders: {
out:{ type: 'console' },
app:{ type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' }
},
categories: {
default: { appenders: [ 'out', 'app' ], level: 'debug' }
}
});
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
```

More information can be found [Log4js - Appenders](https://nomiddlename.github.io/log4js-node/appenders.html) and [must have a property "appenders" of type object. #500](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/issues/500)